# How can i use hibernate 2 level cache by using Guava

Tags: hibernate, guava, second-level-cache

I want to use hibernate 2 level cache using Guava cache.
but i can't found Guava's `RegionFactory` implementation.

could you help me how to use Guava cache for hibernate 2 level cache?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use JCache with an [adapter](https://github.com/ocafebabe/guava-jcache). A more robust adapter, via a Guava-like cache, is provided by [Caffeine](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine).

Comment: Why exactly do you want to use Guava for this? Infinspan, Hazelcast, EhCache and others have had working Hibernate 2 level cache implementations for years that are tried and tested. I'd suggest you try either of them. p.s. I work on the Infinispan project.